# Missing Check In button name and icon in Review Tab (Sitecore 8.2)

Tags: sitecore-client, workflow

In the Content Editor, on the Review tab, in the Workflow group. The Check In button name and icon is not showing, but the button itself is clickable and appends description.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 1**

Here is the code that Render the `Check In` button:

```
private void RenderCheckIn(Item item)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) item, "item");
  string str1 = Translate.Text("Check In");
  string str2 = "Office/16x16/check.png";
  Item checkInItem = this.GetCheckInItem();
  if (checkInItem != null)
  {
    str1 = checkInItem["Phrase"];
    str2 = checkInItem.Appearance.Icon;
  }
  MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
  this.Options.Controls.Add((System.Web.UI.Control) menuItem);
  menuItem.Header = str1;
  menuItem.Icon = str2;
  menuItem.Click = "item:checkin";
}
```

What it does, it fetch the item from the Core Database at the following path:

```
/sitecore/system/Settings/Workflow/Check In
```

So, you need to make sure that the Check In Item has a value from the field `Phrase`.

Normally, the icons are retrieved from the cache. Go to the path `Website/temp/IconCache/office/16x16` and see if the `check.png` is present.

Here is a screenshot of the Inspect Tab.

[image]

Try to inspect the element and see if the `src` has the path. Below is the icon that needs to be present in the cache folder:

[image]

You may copy the image and save it to the path `Website/temp/IconCache/office/16x16` under the name of `check.png`

Comment: Where can I find that path Hishaam?

Comment: You need to go to the Website Folder. Then navigate to `temp/IconCache/office/16x16`. If the directories are not present, you may create it so that you can paste the image

Comment: Where can I find the code behind this?

Comment: Why do you require the code behind? Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: How about the button name? Do you have any idea why it's not showing?

Comment: I accessed the path already. Image wasn't there. How about the Check In name?

Comment: It might be due to the fact that since the button is not present, it did not place the text itself. Try to add the provided image from the answer to the provided path and see if it comes on

Comment: The button is present, it's working fine. When you hover the mouse to the button area, the tooltip appears, but it has no button name and icon. But the button itself is working fine

Comment: Have you paste the image in the folder as I mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, I already did.

Comment: Can you provide the inspect element result of the Check In button in your question?

Comment: Do you know which file I can see the inspect element codes?

Comment: From your Sitecore instance, switch to your core database and navigate to the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Workflow/Check in` and see if the Phrase has the value Check in

Comment: Yes there is a value Check In

Comment: Wild guess but are you possible using client translations for any exotic language? In what language do all other UI elements render?

Comment: Um, im still new to sitecore, I still have no idea what are you talking about Drazen. Hehe. Sorry.